# view function not rendering data on fron

Tags: generics

I am getting error ro unpack(2).

**models.py**

```
class Min
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TemplateView` uses `extra_context` and not `extra_content` so just change:

```
extra_content = {'ticket_type': Ticket.objects.all() }
```

to:

```
extra_context = {'ticket_type': Ticket.objects.all() }
```